# Printing Array with componentsJoinedByString: method

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsstring, xcode4

Hey guys im using the method above like:

```
string = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

this prints out each obj in my array, but what it prints out is:

```
{
Selected = 0;
name = "boots";
number = 69;
}
{
Selected = 0;
name = house;
number = 1001;
}
}
Selected = 0;
name = shirt;
number = 1234;
}
{
Selected = 0;
name = Brewski;
number = 4567;
}



 and i just want it to print out:

 Brewski
 Boots...

etc..
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The objects in your array seem to be dictionaries. You should do this instead.

```
[[array valueForKey:@"name"] componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"]
```